# Have ffplay output current time in millisecond resolution

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, format

What are the arguments for `ffplay` to output the duration/time-stamp of the current frame in **millisecond** resolution (dumping it to `stderr` or `stdout`, not embedding or overlaying it into the video)?

Right now playing a video (and pausing it) will look like this:

```
~$ ffplay -i video.mp4 -hide_banner -loglevel 8 -stats
   2.09 A-V: -0.004 fd=   6 aq=   31KB vq=   84KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Note that the current time, 2.09, is in "centi-seconds" (one hundredth of a second), not millisecond (one thousandeth of a second).

Ideally, it would output only the current time in millisecond resolution:

```
~$ ffplay -i video.mp4 -hide_banner -loglevel 8 -stats <enter magic arguments here>
   2.093
```

Comment: You can't, it's fixed width to 2 decimal places.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Maybe there is a way to build ffmpeg so that ffplay will show it with ms resolution? Or yet another way to retrieve that information from the process (pipe)?

Comment: Sure. It's a format specifier in `video_refresh(()` See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/973540118a82d1dbaa3d4ae08b7014eb434ef82b/fftools/ffplay.c#L1723

Comment: I couldn't see how I could affect that through the build of ffmpeg, so I submitted a PR:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/pull/346
Feel free to close it if it's silly/erroneous.

Comment: Patches are received through mailing-list, not github. In any case, you can make the change locally and build.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this awesome feedback! I'll pick this up tomorrow and try to post some conclusion here. Thank you again!